# How to make Google Now microphone icon using CSS3?

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, css-shapes

I am trying to create the 'Google Now' microphone icon using pure CSS3.
The icon features a white microphone on a red circular background.
I tried font-awesome but in vain
I need your help to complete this task
No animations or functionality, just the icon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Now Icon **Only with CSS**
output :

[image: google now icon made with CSS]

```css
body {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.gn {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5% auto;
  background-color: #FE2222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}

 :before,
 :after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.gn:after {
  top: 30%;
  left: 43%;
  height: 15%;
  width: 14%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.gn:before {
  top: 40%;
  left: 43%;
  height: 15%;
  width: 14%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

.mc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 37%;
  height: 24%;
  width: 26.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mc:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.5em solid #fff;
  background: none;
}

.mc:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gn"><div class="mc"></div></div>
```

Comment: good design but if i use this any copyright problem will come from google

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/dyp32396/1/)**

html

```
<div class=container><i class=icon-microphone></i></div>
```

css

```
@import url(http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
 * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    width:150px;
    background-color:#e74c3c;
    display:block;
    margin:100px auto 0px auto;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 2px #bdc3c7;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:.3s all ease-in;
    position:relative;
}
.icon-microphone {
    color:white;
    font-size:60px;
    line-height:150px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    transition:.1s all ease-in;
}
.container:hover {
    background-color:#27ae60;
}
.container:active {
    background-color:#e74c3c;
}
.container:active .icon-microphone {
    color:#ecf0f1;
}
```

Comment: are you sure it's working on firefox? i just see a unicode replacement.